# Programmatically close an interstitial ad

Tags: android, admob, ads, interstitial

I want to make sure that interstitial ads on Android, using the Android AdMob SDK, can be closed.
After some research, it seems to me that this is not possible due to the ad being a separate activity.
What I want to do is close the ad after 5 seconds. 
Can someone assure me that closing an interstitial ad is impossible or if there's a hack?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

It's going to be a very late answer but I faced similar issue. A trick can be to call the back button event programmatically.

`this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));`

As whenever you press on back button the interstitial ad is closed so firing the back button event will eventually close the interstitial ad. Rest depends on the requirement.

Comment: could you share more. details on how to do this.

Comment: It didn't worked out!

Answer (score 4):

You can get a reference of the Admob Interstitial activity and call `finish()` on it when you want to close it, by implementing `ActivityLifecycleCallbacks`:

```
private final Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks activityLifecycleCallbacks = new Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks() {
        @Override
        public void onActivityCreated(@NonNull Activity activity, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onActivityCreated: " + activity.getClass());
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStarted(@NonNull Activity activity) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onActivityStarted: " + activity.getClass());
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityResumed(@NonNull Activity activity) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onActivityResumed: " + activity.getClass());
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityPaused(@NonNull Activity activity) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onActivityPaused: " + activity.getClass());
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityStopped(@NonNull Activity activity) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onActivityStopped: " + activity.getClass());
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivitySaveInstanceState(@NonNull Activity activity, @NonNull Bundle outState) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onActivitySaveInstanceState: " + activity.getClass());
        }

        @Override
        public void onActivityDestroyed(@NonNull Activity activity) {
            Log.e(TAG, "onActivityDestroyed: " + activity.getClass());
        }
    };


MyApplication.getInstance().registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(activityLifecycleCallbacks);


E/TAG: onActivityCreated: class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity
E/TAG: onActivityStarted: class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity
E/TAG: onActivityResumed: class com.google.android.gms.ads.AdActivity
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to programatically close an interstitial ad.

Comment: But any hack is possible ?

Answer (score 0):

For new readers.
use:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activity.getClass());
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    activity.startActivity(intent);



        @Override
        public void onAdOpened() {
            // Code to be executed when the ad is displayed.
            Log.d("mInterstitialAd", "onAdOpened  ");
            fullscreenAdShowing = true;
            new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()).postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if(!fullscreenAdShowing){
                        return;
                    }
                    Log.d("mInterstitialAd", "onAdOpened  Handler 5 seconds run");
                    Intent intent = new Intent(activity, activity.getClass());
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);
                    activity.startActivity(intent);

                }
            }, 5000);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAdClosed() {
            // Code to be executed when when the interstitial ad is closed.
            Log.d("mInterstitialAd", "onAdClosed  loadAd");
            fullscreenAdShowing = false;

            mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());

        }
```