# How to hide interstitial ads in Android

Tags: android, admob

I am working with AdMob in Android, and I am using both interstitial and banner ads. I want to hide interstitial ads, but it seems that there is not any suitable methods for hiding it.

Please help if you have any solutions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you want to hide it?

Comment: on button click

Answer (score 0):

Taking answer from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26968593/6549598)

```
this.dispatchKeyEvent(new KeyEvent(KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN, KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK));
```

As whenever you press on back button the interstitial ad is closed so firing the back button event will eventually close the interstitial ad. Rest depends on the requirement.

> Note: This is not an official way of doing this. It is just and hack/workaround.

As [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22163379/6549598) points

> It is not possible to programmatically close an interstitial ad.

Hope this helps.